# Converting Flat File to Java Objects

Tags: java, flat-file

Does anybody know of any good libraries to convert a flat file to Java objects?  I found [flatworm](http://javaconfessions.com/2009/04/writing-flat-files-in-java-with.html) but I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: If it's something like a CSV (or any delimited file) or XML, it's trivial to read it in and create objects out of it. Could you elaborate on the file format and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Flat file is a pretty broad category.  Text file?  CSV file? Serialized Object file?  What's in the "flat file"

Comment: nothing wrong with it, just want to see if there are alternatives that might be better suited to my needs

Comment: flat files are fixed width column text files - correct. i need to parse such files.

Comment: You are looking for FFPOJO: https://github.com/ffpojo/ffpojo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FFP - Flat file parsing library**
 
http://jffp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 9):

Quick update: flatworm has not been active for quite a while, there is a fork named BeanIO:
http://www.beanio.org/

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this **[JFlat](http://code.google.com/p/jflat/)**, But it seems this Framework provides conversion from Flat file to Java object.

Similarly [BeanIO](http://www.beanio.org/) and [Jsefa](http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/quick-tutorial.html) also provides a simple and flexible API.

You can try with [FlatPack](http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/index.html) - but it is OLD and the docs are not good as JFlat or BeanIO

Apache Camel has [Flatpack component](http://camel.apache.org/flatpack.html) as well as from 2.10 it has [BeanIO component](http://camel.apache.org/beanio.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, that I wrote that uses Java Annotations is JFileHelpers - http://jfilehelpers.com

An example of annotated bean:

```
@FixedLengthRecord()
public class Customer {
    @FieldFixedLength(4)
    public Integer custId;

    @FieldAlign(alignMode=AlignMode.Right)
    @FieldFixedLength(20)
    public String name;

    @FieldFixedLength(3)
    public Integer rating;

    @FieldTrim(trimMode=TrimMode.Right)
    @FieldFixedLength(10)
    @FieldConverter(converter = ConverterKind.Date,
        format = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    public Date addedDate;

    @FieldFixedLength(3)
    @FieldOptional
    public String stockSymbol;
}
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
  FileHelperEngine<Customer> engine =
      new FileHelperEngine<Customer>(Customer.class);
  List<Customer> customers =
      new ArrayList<Customer>();

  customers = engine.readResource(
      "/samples/customers-fixed.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also give a try to [Fixedformat4j](https://github.com/jeyben/fixedformat4j). 
I like the annotations approach and it's very simple to define a custom field format.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to consider [JRecordBind](http://jrecordbind.org/) (I'm its author)

Unlike others, it's able to both parse and create flat files and it uses plain XML Schema (so you don't have to learn yet another configuration syntax).
Some users recycle the same XSD for producing both webservice and flat files output.

ps: I've recently moved the code to [github](https://github.com/ffissore/jrecordbind)