# FlatFile Processing

Tags: java, regex, flat-file

I have a flat file which contain data with Fixed length,Is there any good approach to parse the data and splitting the lines using a regular occurrence,ie for every occurrence starting with "02" should be a new line and it should be stored some where?I have gone through Flatworm which uses a XML,which will be lengthy process if lot of fixed length data is to be inserted?

Note:I have gone through some samples of Flat file parsing in stackoverflow using Flatworm and FFP,but cant be a standard one,as I am trying to do it as a utility class.

Text file seems to be like:

> 022010015450696611KR  GERGIN  MR vvvv 020100145078211PETRO  EMILIAN MR
>   vvv

Comment: write a loop, perhaps? This might turn out to consume the least amount of developer time.

Comment: Might be interesting for you: [Converting Flat File to Java Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294405/converting-flat-file-to-java-objects)

Comment: What database are you using? Chances are that there is a tool already for this purpose, like [sqlldr for Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ), I think DTS for MS SQL Server, etc... Of course, this is only applciable, if you don't want to do this programmatically...

Comment: @ppeterka I am using Oracle as DB

Comment: @ppeterka I need to do it programatically

Comment: @Prabhathkesav sorry, then in that case, this is not applicable... Unless you want to start sqlldr from `Runtime.exec()`, which would be very ugly, and absolutely unflexible...